# ArticleDate managed property offset by a day

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, managed-property

When using my ArticleDate managed property, it is offset by a day. So if the article is created the 1. June 2015, the ArticleDate property holds the value 31. May 2015.

Why, and is it possible to fix in any way. This breaks my sorting-query of articles, because the article created 1. June, is in the interval of 1. May - 31. May.

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint stores DateTime in UTC format and when the datetime values are displayed in OOTB SharePoint UI, SharePoint adds the  UTC offset to show the correct date. So you will need to find a way to add the UTC offset to the ArticleDate  property before you do sorting.

See this [article](http://itblog.wolthaus.net/2011/09/sharepoint-stores-dates-in-utc-time/) about the same.

Comment: Any ideas on how to add offset to the property, any articles about this issue? Where to modify, and so.